# How to extract subarray [*attributes] into any new array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have following array, It is a result of typecasting from an object. I get the following output of array data after typecasting object to array,

```
 Array
(
[*table] => inspector_details
[*connection] => 
[*primaryKey] => id
[*perPage] => 15
[incrementing] => 1
[timestamps] => 1
[*attributes] => Array
    (
        [id] => 94
        [firstname] => Aamir39
        [address1] => 
        [address2] => 
        [city] => 
        [state] => 
        [is_frozen] => 1
        [email] => aamir.shoebn39@otssolutions.com
        [is_email_private] => 0
        [status] => 2
        [latitude] => 
        [longitude] => 
        [created_at] => 2016-07-12 15:40:14
        [updated_at] => 2016-07-13 11:40:44
        [zip] => 0
        [company] => OTS
        [website] => 
        [phone] => 
        [is_phone_private] => 0
        [company_began_date] => 0000-00-00
        [logo] => 
        [freetext] => 
        [lic_name] => 
        [lic_id] => 
        [lic_url] => 
    )

[*original] => Array
    (
        [id] => 94
        [firstname] => Aamir39
        [address1] => 
        [address2] => 
        [city] => 
        [state] => 
        [is_frozen] => 1
        [email] => aamir.shoebn39@otssolutions.com
        [is_email_private] => 0
        [status] => 2
        [latitude] => 
        [longitude] => 
        [created_at] => 2016-07-12 15:40:14
        [updated_at] => 2016-07-13 11:40:44
        [zip] => 0
        [company] => OTS
        [website] => 
        [phone] => 
        [is_phone_private] => 0
        [company_began_date] => 0000-00-00
        [logo] => 
        [freetext] => 
        [lic_name] => 
        [lic_id] => 
        [lic_url] => 
    )

[*relations] => Array
    (
    )

[*hidden] => Array
    (
    )

[*visible] => Array
    (
    )

[*appends] => Array
    (
    )

[*fillable] => Array
    (
    )

[*guarded] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )

[*dates] => Array
    (
    )

[*dateFormat] => 
[*casts] => Array
    (
    )

[*touches] => Array
    (
    )

[*observables] => Array
    (
    )

[*with] => Array
    (
    )

[*morphClass] => 
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] => 
)
```

I want to extract [*attributes] sub array in to new array called $errordata[].

My code is follows,

```
   $emaildataarray = (array)$emaildata;
   array_push($errordata, $emaildataarray['*attributes']);
```

BUT it show me error,

```
  Undefined index: *attributes
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is the *attributes part of the array described when you do `var_dump($emaildataarray)`

Comment: @BeetleJuice Like this     
                                       ["*attributes"]=>
  array(25) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(94)....................

Comment: Then your code `$emaildataarray['*attributes']` should work.  How do you access `*attributes` when your data is still an object?

Comment: I'm converting object data to array. My purpose is to get attributes array. I will post here my object data.

Comment: I understand your purpose.  I'd like to know, when your data is still in object form, how would you access that property, say if you wanted to get the first name.  Your answer may help me work through the problem.

Comment: Without converting object to array, I can access first name like this way : $emaildata->firstname

Comment: are you sure that `$emaildata->firstname` returns `Aamir39`? Because the array you printed in your question shows `*attributes` between the top level and `firstname` so I am surprised that you can get to first name without going through attributes. Could you confirm please?

Comment: Yes I am also surprised it doesn't print attributs data. Anyways I got a solution for that. I'm using Laravel so when I get data in object, I use toArray() method, then it only return you ['*attributes'] array data.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Got solution from here http://laravel.io/forum/02-16-2014-iterate-through-model-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I extract ['*attributes'] data using  toArray() method in laravel. It will automatically convert object data into array.

I was using

```
  $emaildata = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
```

then Added toArray().

```
 $emaildata = User::whereEmail($email)->first()->toArray();
```

Thanks.

Comment: got solution from here http://laravel.io/forum/02-16-2014-iterate-through-model-attributes

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'll delete my answer.  I suggest you paste the code in your answer so that people who see this later will have a solution even if the page you linked to goes away.